# Task Scheduler -- how to expand /export the "Show Active tasks" window -- Windows server Enterprise Edition 2007:

Tags: windows, task-scheduler, export, csv

For the Task Scheduler -- how to expand the "Show Active tasks" window -- This is for Windows server Enterprise Edition (release date: 2007).

Is there a way to export the data to a .csv file or something similar?

Comment: Ironically, it seems to expand if one clicks on "Task Status" which seems counter-intuitive.  However, if anyone has a better or more complete answer, please post.  I personally cannot find any convenient way to export the data.

Comment: `Windows server Enterprise Edition 2007` - I've never heard of that.

Comment: @joeqwerty -- Well it's "Enterprise Edition" and it is dated 2007.  I edited the post to clarify this.

Comment: That would probably be Windows Server 2008.

Comment: You can check by running get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select name in Powershell.

Comment: I independently found out one can also use Command-line:  SCHTASKS /QUERY  -- from:  https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/35888-where-my-disabled-tasks-located-win-10-a.html

Comment: @JosephDoggie That will just list the Operating System version.

Comment: The Command-line I posted above works on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Win 8 or 2012 and newer, you can use this:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Where State -Like "Running" | Export-Csv -Path path\to\csv
```

But you can also use cmd prompt:

```
schtasks /query /FO CSV > path\to\csv
```

That list will include every Scheduled Task, so you'll either want to use something like Excel's "Filter" tool or use another tool to parse through the output and grab only the rows where the 3rd column contains "Running." A batch file running a `for` loop would definitely work.

Comment: The scheduled tasks cmdlet doesn't exist in Server 2008.

Comment: @Davidw Oops, didn't know that. Thanks! I'll update to use cmd instead.

Comment: It's not version dependent, but OS dependent. (I have 5.1 on my Windows 2008R2 VM, and it's not listed.)

Comment: @Davidw hopefully accurate now?

Answer (score 0):

I independently found out one can also use Command-line: SCHTASKS /QUERY
 -- this works on the system that I use.

Source: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65255-export-task-task-scheduler-windows.html